# How to read contents from a text file in java from a specified location in hard drive using netbeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans

am having a simple programe to  read contents from a text file using netbeans IDE in java. I want to specify the loacation as "D:/input.txt". How can I do it.Thanks in advance.

```
public class Abcd { 
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
 { 
 FileInputStream in = null; 
 FileOutputStream out = null; 

 try { 
 in = new FileInputStream("input.txt");   //specify exact location here.
 out = new FileOutputStream("output.txt"); 

 int c; 
 while ((c = in.read()) != -1) { 
 out.write(c); 
 } 
 }finally { 
 if (in != null) { 
 in.close(); 
 } 
 if (out != null) { 
 out.close(); 
 } 
 }} 
}
```

Comment: You can use `D:/input.txt`.What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the complete path directly:

```
in = new FileInputStream("D:\\input.txt");
```

And to avoid incompatibility between different Operative Systems, you can use [`file.separator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html):

```
String sep = System.getProperty("file.separator");
//...
in = new FileInputStream("E:" + sep + "input.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

from java 7 onwards you can use try with resource so that its not required to close the stream manually in finally loop

```
public class Abcd { 
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
 { 
 FileInputStream in = null; 
 FileOutputStream out = null; 

 try ( in = new FileInputStream("D:/input.txt");  
 out = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");){ 


 int c; 
 while ((c = in.read()) != -1) { 
 out.write(c); 
 } 
 }} 
}
```

**Note** the code is not tested

Answer (score 1):

This is working example with handling `Exception` can raised as `IOException`, `FileNotFoundException`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileInputStream in = null; 
     FileOutputStream out = null; 

     try { 
         in = new FileInputStream("D:\\input.txt");   //specify exact location here.
         out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\output.txt"); 

         int c; 
         while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {                 
             out.write(c); 
         } 

     } catch(FileNotFoundException fe) {
        fe.printStackTrace();

     } catch(IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();

     } finally { 

         if (in != null) { 
             try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
         } 
         if (out != null) { 
             try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
         } 

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\input.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```